# JCache with EHCache implementation

Tags: ehcache, jcache

Does EHCache implemenation of JCache supports Distributed caching feature?

My requirement is Distributed Client-Server Cache: Multiple cache (clustered) nodes, collaborating in a distributed fashion and executing in isolation from the client application.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Note: I am a developer working on Ehcache

Ehcache, depending on version, has two different ways it is integrated with JSR-107 / JCache:

- Version 2.x needs the [ehcache-jcache wrapper](https://github.com/ehcache/ehcache-jcache/releases)
- [Version 3](https://github.com/ehcache/ehcache3/releases), under active development, is a native implementation of it.

In both cases, while using the JSR-107 / JCache API in your application, you can benefit from the whole set of options available to native Ehcache. This includes the clustering support:

- It is available with Ehcache 2.10.1 and Terracotta 4.3.1 today
- It will be included in Ehcache 3. It has been released and is available with Ehcache 3.1 and above.